# How to do attr_accessor_with_default in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Some code that I had that used `attr_accessor_with_default` in a rails model is now giving me a deprecation warning, telling me to "Use Ruby instead!"

So, thinking that maybe there was a new bit in `ruby 1.9.2` that made `attr_accessor` handle defaults, I googled it, but I don't see that.  I did see a bunch of methods to override `attr_accessor` to handle defaults though.

Is that what they mean when they tell me to "Use Ruby?"  Or am I supposed to write full getters/setters now?  Or is there some new way I can't find?

Comment: I don't consider this best practice in any way.  Though I'm curious why you want to use such a pattern.

Comment: Very simply because I want a bool to default to true.  Why wouldn't this be a best practice? At the time it was a language feature, very succinct and easily read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
attr_accessor :pancakes

def after_initialize
     return unless new_record?
     self.pancakes = 11
end
```

> This ensures that the value is initialized to some default for new record only.

Comment: This seems to be dependent on ActiveRecord. FYI for the next person to come along.

Answer (score 32):

[This apidock page](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/Module/attr_accessor_with_default) suggests to just do it in the initialize method.

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :pancakes

  def initialize 
    @pancakes = true
    super
  end
end
```

Don't forget to call `super` especially when using ActiveRecord or similar.

Comment: By the way: this should be the validated answer, as it comes without any dependency.

Comment: This won't work in Rails 4.2. Will get "wrong number of arguments error", instead use def initialize(attributes={}) Doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html

Answer (score 5):

Since you probably know your data quite well, it can be quite acceptable to assume `nil` is not a valid value.

This means you can do away with an `after_initialize`, as this will be executed for every object you create. As several people have pointed out, this is (potentially) disastrous for performance. Also, inlining the method as in the example is deprecated in Rails 3.1 anyway.

To 'use Ruby instead' I would take this approach:

```
attr_writer :pancakes

def pancakes
  return 12 if @pancakes.nil?
  @pancakes
end
```

So trim down the Ruby magic just a little bit and write your own getter. After all this does exactly what you are trying to accomplish, and it's nice and simple enough for anyone to wrap his/her head around.

Comment: Sorry, but that's too much bloat/makes everything to complex if used often.  But if you really really want to take that road: `def pancakes ; @pancakes || 12 ; end`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the downvote (not)! Your "improvement" has a serious flaw. It will return true when the value of the instance variable is false. You see that is exactly wrong? Great. This is why I added the "bloat" to check for nil instead. Which, depending on the circumstances, can be quite acceptable.

Comment: I upvoted it back up, because its a valid answer. My only question would be, when the object is saved, is it going to use that default because the save is going to use that accessor?  Or would you still have to have the default in the table, meaning tracking it in two places which is "bad."  I guess I could just go try it out. :)  And to write the "bloat" on one line you could just write: def pancakes; @pancakes.nil? ? 12 : @pancakes; end. :)

Comment: I generally prefer one-liners `def pancakes ; @pancakes.nil? ? 12 : @pancakes ; end`.

Comment: Why would anybody want to have a boolean field that has nil values masked as value 12? O.O Wow.. don't do that. It's insane. Life don't need to be this complicated.

Comment: As I found out, you shouldn't use this pattern if you want to initialize an array. Not if you expect << to work as the first array operation. Thinking it through, it makes sense. `def arr; @arr.nil? ? [] : @arr; end` will create a new array every time you use <<, but nothing assigns that array back to @arr. I ended up with `def arr; @arr ||= []; end` as that will assign @arr first time round. As for Joost's objection, I think that if an attribute can hold both 12 and false, it may be time to have a long, hard look at your code... But in the (hopefully) rare occasions you need to, bloat away.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ooooold question, but the general problem still crops up - and I found myself here.

The other answers are varied and interesting, but I found problems with all of them when initializing arrays (especially as I wanted to be able to use them at a class level before initialize was called on the instance). I had success with:

```
attr_writer :pancakes

def pancakes
  @pancakes ||= []
end
```

If you use = instead of ||= you will find that the << operator fails for adding the first element to the array. (An anonymous array is created, a value is assigned to it, but it's never assigned back to @pancakes.)

For example:

```
obj.pancakes
#=> []
obj.pancakes << 'foo'
#=> ['foo']
obj.pancakes
#=> [] 
#???#!%$#@%FRAK!!!
```

As this is quite a subtle problem and could cause a few head scratches, I thought it was worth mentioning here.

This pattern will need to be altered for a bool, for example if you want to default to false:

```
attr_writer :pancakes

def pancakes
  @pancakes.nil? ? @pancakes = false : @pancakes
end
```

Although you could argue that the assignment isn't strictly necessary when dealing with a bool.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical in 1.9.2 for initializing instance variables that you set up with `attr_accessor`. But there is the [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) callback:

> The `after_initialize` callback will be called whenever an Active Record object is instantiated, either by directly using new or when a record is loaded from the database. It can be useful to avoid the need to directly override your Active Record `initialize` method.

So:

```
attr_accessor :pancakes
after_initialize :init

protected
def init
    @pancakes = 11
end
```

This is safer than something like this:

```
def pancakes
    @pancakes ||= 11
end
```

because `nil` or `false` might be perfectly valid values after initialization and assuming that they're not can cause some *interesting* bugs.

Comment: Just a warning that if you do `Post.all` and it returns a set of 1,000 `Post` objects, it's going to run this `after_initialize` callback on all of them. Not the end of the world, but something to be aware of as  you scale.

Comment: @coreyward: If you do `Post.all` in real code then an extra 1000 method calls is the least of your worries.

Comment: True, but if it's in the Rails Getting Started Guide, it's in lot's of new-Rails-developer codebases. ;)

Comment: Makes sense, and I wouldn't use Post.all. However, with Rails desire to simplify everything why the heck would they deprecate _with_default?

Comment: @Vulgrin: I don't know, sometimes the Rails people ave more attitude than sense (that should get me some dirty looks :)

Comment: @mu - yeah, after working with RoR for a year or so, I'm pretty scared of the platform just because of the capricious nature of deprecations and major changes going on on minor versions. Weird stuff.

Comment: @Vulgrin: Never mind the lack of documented interfaces, tracing through the source really isn't a substitute for a simple "it is supposed to behave like X" statement. And the fanboyism. Hopefully they'll grow up.

Comment: This seems to be dependent on ActiveRecord. FYI for the next person to come along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if just using Rails implementation would work for you:

http://apidock.com/rails/Module/attr_accessor_with_default

```
def attr_accessor_with_default(sym, default = nil, &block)
  raise 'Default value or block required' unless !default.nil? || block
  define_method(sym, block_given? ? block : Proc.new { default })
  module_eval(      def #{sym}=(value)                        # def age=(value)        class << self; attr_reader :#{sym} end  #   class << self; attr_reader :age end        @#{sym} = value                         #   @age = value      end                                       # end, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify default values for instances of any class (not only `ActiveRecords`) after applying patch to `Module`:

```
class Zaloop

  attr_accessor var1: :default_value, var2: 2

  def initialize
    self.initialize_default_values
  end

end

puts Zaloop.new.var1 # :default_value
```

Patch for module:

```
Module.module_eval do

  alias _original_attr_accessor attr_accessor
  def attr_accessor(*args)
    attr_names = extract_default_values args
    _original_attr_accessor *attr_names
  end

  alias _original_attr_reader attr_reader
  def attr_reader(*args)
    attr_names = extract_default_values args
    _original_attr_reader *attr_names
  end

  def extract_default_values(args)
    @default_values ||= {}
    attr_names = []
    args.map do |arg|
      if arg.is_a? Hash
        arg.each do |key, value|
          define_default_initializer if @default_values.empty?
          @default_values[key] = value
          attr_names << key
        end
      else
        attr_names << arg
      end
    end
    attr_names
  end

  def define_default_initializer
    default_values = @default_values
    self.send :define_method, :initialize_default_values do
      default_values.each do |key, value|
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, value)
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize_default_values
    # Helper for autocomplete and syntax highlighters
  end

end
```