# best way to set a default value on a property without ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby

I thought that this question ( [How to do attr_accessor_with_default in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052509/how-to-do-attr-accessor-with-default-in-ruby) ) answered my question, but I'm not using ActiveRecord and [after_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) depends on it.

What's the Ruby best practice for implementing a default value for an `attr_accessor`? Is [this](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) the closest thing to documentation about it? Should I stop using `attr_accessor` since it is private?

Comment: You don't want `@@` vars unless you're SURE you know why you do. Class-level instance variables (see my answer below) are a hair more work, but have less surprises with respect to subclasses. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see what's going on now, I'm gonna remove the edit. I was under the mistaken impression that attr_accessor was a Rails thing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
class Foo
  # class-level instance variable

  # setting initial value (optional)
  @class_var = 42  

  # making getter/setter methods on the class itself
  class << self
    attr_accessor :class_var
  end

  # instance-level variable getter/setter methods
  attr_accessor :inst_var
  def initialize
    # setting initial value (optional)
    @inst_var = 17
  end
end

p Foo.class_var
#=> 42
Foo.class_var = 99
p Foo.class_var
#=> 99

f1 = Foo.new
f2 = Foo.new
f2.inst_var = 1
p [f1.inst_var, f2.inst_var]
#=> [17,1]
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. What about `attr_accessor` being private? It's peculiar coming from C# that Ruby lets me use things that are private like this. It's like private is just a suggestion. Odd.

Comment: It doesn't make private methods, but is itself private: it's intended to be used only when you open the class. You can always re-open a class later, or do `Foo.instance_eval{ attar_accessor :bar }` or use [`__send__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__) which bypasses restrictions. Yes, Ruby gives you sharp knives to play with, if you want.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly what I need. When I do `@debug = false
  class << self
    attr_accessor :debug
  end` and create an instance of a class that inherits from that class, the debug property is nil.  I'm expecting 'false' there, since it has a default value. Sorry for the screwy formatting.

Comment: I got it, I needed to call `super` in the initialize in the sub-class.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify some of the code snippets above that might be misleading, the best way to set a default value on a Ruby instance variable is NOT the same behavior as PHP or Python.

The simple solution is to set default values for your instance variables is to set them inside the `initialize()` method:

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :foo
    # @foo = 'This is totally ignored! Do not try to set a default value here!'  
    def initialize
      @foo = 'default'    
    end
end

x = MyClass.new
print x.foo  # tada!
```

Answer (score 1):

@Phrogz gave a nice solution, but you should know more about it.

Here you make a `class-level instance variable`, which is not really a class variable, but who cares, because after you initialize a real class variable with the same name, you lose an old reference.

To inspect the fakeness, use the above code, but with an array:

```
class Foo
  @class_var = [42]
  class << self
    attr_accessor :class_var
  end
end
b = [Foo.class_var]
Foo.class_var = 69
p b # still [[42]]
```

And you are going to get a problem, when trying to get the variable via `@@` which was supposed for a real class variable.

```
class Bar
  @class_var = [42]
  class << self
    attr_accessor :class_var
  end
  def biz
    self.class.class_var
  end
  def baz
    @@class_var
  end
end
p Bar.new.biz # self.class. is kinda a way to emulate the reference from outside
p Bar.new.baz # and exception, because you don't really have a class variable defined yet!
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to specify default values for instance variables of any class is to patch `Module`, and then write set defaults like this:

```
class Zaloop

  attr_accessor var1: :default_value, var2: 2

  def initialize
    initialize_default_values
  end

end

puts Zaloop.new.var1 # :default_value
```

Patch for module:

```
Module.module_eval do

  alias _original_attr_accessor attr_accessor
  def attr_accessor(*args)
    attr_names = extract_default_values args
    _original_attr_accessor *attr_names
  end

  alias _original_attr_reader attr_reader
  def attr_reader(*args)
    attr_names = extract_default_values args
    _original_attr_reader *attr_names
  end

  def extract_default_values(args)
    @default_values ||= {}
    attr_names = []
    args.map do |arg|
      if arg.is_a? Hash
        arg.each do |key, value|
          define_default_initializer if @default_values.empty?
          @default_values[key] = value
          attr_names << key
        end
      else
        attr_names << arg
      end
    end
    attr_names
  end

  def define_default_initializer
    default_values = @default_values
    self.send :define_method, :initialize_default_values do
      default_values.each do |key, value|
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, value)
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize_default_values
    # Helper for autocomplete and syntax highlighters
  end

end
```