# How do set a default attribute value for a module class

Tags: ruby

Up until recently this use to work fine:

```
module Demo
  class << self
    attr_accessor_with_default :x, "hey"
  end
end
```

However that's no longer the case.

attr_accessor_with_default has been removed and I am left without a clue how to set this attribute a default value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052509/how-to-do-attr-accessor-with-default-in-ruby

Answer (score 4):

For normal instance variables, you'd just set the variable to its default value inside initialize. For class instance variables, you can set it inside the class body:

```
module Demo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :x
  end

  @x = "hey"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me...

```
class Demo
  attr_accessor :x

  def initialize
    @x= "hey"
  end 
end
```

Then it can be called `Demo.new.x` => `hey`